# "Применительно к..." в середине предложения: выделение запятыми

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Не смог нигде в Интернете найти объяснение, следует ли выделять запятыми фрагмент предложения, начинающийся с конструкции "применительно к".

Например:

> Каталог это тоже файл, просто с соответствующим атрибутом, поэтому слово filenames(,) применительно к именам каталогов(,) не является ошибкой, хотя и может звучать непривычно.

Нужно или нет? И почему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данном случае я бы не стал ставить запятые:

*Каталог – это тоже файл, просто с соответствующим атрибутом, поэтому слово filenames **применительно к именам каталогов** не является ошибкой, хотя и может звучать непривычно.*

Вообще, обособление таких оборотов факультативно. Это зависит от многих факторов (см. [**Обстоятельства, выраженные существительными**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=114), справочник Розенталя).

В приведённом предложении словосочетание "применительно к именам каталогов", как я думаю, не является дополнительной, попутной, вставочной информацией, которая, как правило, выделяется запятыми или скобками. Оно непосредственно относится к слову ***filenames***.

В Национальном корпусе русского языка сочетание ***"применительно к"*** встречается [довольно часто](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&ct=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BA) и запятые ставятся или не ставятся в силу вкладываемого смысла, структруры предложения и логических акцентов. Я выбрал те, которые максимально соответствуют предложению из вопроса:

*Унизительный этот термин **применительно к лучшим людям отчизны** шокировал Вову.* [М. К. Кантор. В ту сторону (2009)]

*Юридическим выражением этого конституционного постулата **применительно к международному гражданскому процессу** выступает доктрина «минимальных контактов».* [Актуальные проблемы теории и практики международного гражданского процесса (2003) // «Арбитражный и гражданский процессы», 24.11.2003]

*Термин «оспаривание» **применительно к решениям третейского суда** является новым для отечественного законодательства о третейских судах.* [Оспаривание решений третейского суда в действующем российском законодательстве (2003) // «Арбитражный и гражданский процессы», 27.10.2003]

*Мне всегда казалось, что слово «акмеизм» **применительно к Мандельштаму** только мешает.* [М. Л. Гаспаров. Записи и выписки (2001)]

*Вообще, слово «пассив» **применительно к семантико-коммуникативным преобразованиям**, конечно, не следует понимать буквально.* [Г. И. Кустова. Производные значения с экспериенциальной составляющей (1999)]

*Впервые этот термин **применительно к вулканам** употребил 150 лет назад известный немецкий ученый-геолог Л. фон Бух.* [И. А. Резанов. Великие катастрофы в истории Земли (1984)]

*Это понятие **применительно к обычным явлениям** выражает наличие у тела одновременного определенного импульса...* [А. К. Сухотин. Парадоксы науки (1978)]

*Слова «внутреннее устройство» **применительно к современным лыжам (а особенно к горным)** отнюдь не преувеличение.* [Леонидов О., Юлин М. «Польский мяч — удачный матч!» // «Химия и жизнь», 1969]

---

Конечно, не исключено и обособление, когда оборот (по контексту и по мнению автора) имеет добавочное значение, например:

*Эволюция знаков, **применительно к взаимоотношениям метрополии и колонии,** на востоке не имела значения.* [Игорь Можейко. При исполнении // «Родина», 1996]

P. S. Между подлежащим ***каталог*** и сказуемым ***файл*** нужно поставить тире.

Comment: Очень подробно и по делу. Спасибо, Александр.

Comment: @user90726  Спасибо за вопрос и оценку! :)